# Angularjs and Chart.js minimal example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm using angular and charts.js to create dynamic charts, but the graphics always show empty, there is any minimal example on how to use both of them?

here a plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/V1gIaCIAixQTcHtBj9YN?p=preview
i'm still learning angular, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

The non working code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="e in encuesta.cuestionario">
          <!--This doesn't works!-->
          <div id="canvas-holder" class="col-sm-4">
            <canvas id="{{'chart-area-'+$index}}" width="250" height="250" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 formulario">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <p>{{e.pregunta}}</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You have a TypeError, the view has not finished loading before you're asking it to `getContext` on the canvas elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple take on your code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/RvtPAcV4JKDkzikeSamM?p=preview

I build the charts into a scope array based on the cuestionario length.

```
for (i = 1; i < $scope.encuesta.cuestionario.length; i++) {
    $scope.charts.push({
        chartId: i
    });
}
```

Then render the charts inside a timeout to let digest complete:

```
function loadCharts() {
    $timeout(function() {
      angular.forEach($scope.charts, function(chart) {
        var ctx = angular.element(document.getElementById("chart-area-" + chart.chartId))[0].getContext("2d");
        window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {
          responsive: true
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The other big thing to note is that we access the element as an array, "[0]":

```
var ctx = angular.element(document.getElementById("chart-area-" + chart.chartId))[0].getContext("2d");
```

Comment: I think you should include the beginning of your last code example, as it is not currently syntactically correct and gives the impression that `getElementById` returns an array (which it never will). Prepending the `var ctx = angular.element(` would make more visual sense.